# Why is not tor relays chain shown in tor browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Why is not tor relays chain shown in tor browser?

When you press lock or onion icon near the url you should see chain like your browser > Germany (ip) > France (ip) > USA (ip) > clearnet site (or relay > relay > relay > onionsite). But I just see "Connection secure" and "permissions". where's that chain? Also theres no button NEW CIRCUIT FOR THIS SITE. Is it ok (at least uncomfortable)? I checked ip, it's differnt. I use whonix with xfce. thanks a lot foryour help.

screenhot:
[image]

i have tor uptodate

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? And is your Tor Browser version up to date?

Comment: Swangie, I know it is wrong to post comments or edits as answers but I do this through tor so I have no access to the question once I restarted tor. Sorry. I hope moderators will edit my question and or take actions on 'answers'. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option is to uninstall the Tor browser completely, then reinstall it again with the latest version. Perhaps something may have gone wrong in the Tor browser's installation and you may have to install it again.

If that still doesn't work, then file an issue in the Tor project's gitlab, located here: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues. List your OS details and browser details so it easier for the Tor project to handle the issue. If you are not able to create the issue yourself, just ask me to do it and I will ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser is this? Not Tor Browser?

Use Tor browser, you will find them, if not!